# How to filter on specific key values in clojure?

Tags: clojure

What is an idiomatic way to get the maps with a specific value for a particular key in a Clojure seq?

E.g. get the maps in a seq `:tag`-ed with `:fubar` value.

```
(filter #(= (% :tag) :fubar) some-seq)
```

This works, but I'm guessing there is some more elegant way to do it...

Comment: Are the values always keywords?

Comment: Yes, the values are always keywords

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(filter (comp #{:fubar} :tag) some-seq)
```